# UnitTest++ and main

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I want to give TDD a try and I've chosen the UnitTest++ framework, but the documentations is almost non-existent (to my knowledge).

My concern is this: in all the tutorials I've seen, they put `UnitTest::RunAllTests()` in the `main()` function. I'm guessing they do it only to simplify the explanation, but I wouldn't want that with my software. Where should I put `UnitTest::RunAllTests()` so that I can have it executed every time I build the software but not when I run it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UnitTest::RunAllTests()` should be put into the `main` function of a separate program, which you compile and run as part of your build process.

Answer (score 0):

One thing we've done in the past is to add a command line argument which makes the main executable run all the tests and then exit. It's fairly easy to arrange some #ifdefs such that this code gets compiled out on release builds. Something like this (it's not very C++ but if you weren't parsing command line arguments already this is the simplest way to do it):

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
#ifdef DEBUG
  if (argc > 1 && !strcmp(argv[2], "-t"))
  {
    return UnitTest::RunAllTests();
  }
#endif

  [rest of program]

}
```